# Audio comes out of only one speaker on a Macbook Pro 7.1

Tags: sound, macbook

Model Identifier: MacBook Pro 6,1
Processor Name: Intel Core i5

Ubuntu 11.10

Audio coming only out of one speaker

Audio Settings Menu:

HARDWARE TAB:
Internal Audio 1 Output/1 Input
Analogue Stereo Duplex

OUTPUT TAB:
Connector - Analogue Headphones (I have no other options available, ANALOG SPEAKER option missing)

Used to work, but Ubuntu broke, again, so had to do a fresh install. Now audio only works as mono, and I cannot change output type.

Any suggestions?

Tried another fresh install, I can still only select HEADPHONES as the output.

Playback is only out of one speaker, mono.

It looks like Ubuntu has decided to no longer see my internal speaker, only headphone output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `alsamixer` show more outputs? try giving the other outputs more volume and see if your sound works then :)

Comment: Yes ALSA mixer shows the speaker outputs. I've now installed 10.10 and it works fine. I think MAC hardware and Ubuntu is not a match made in heaven. However all good now, thanks. I will try 12.04 when released...